# how to remove software update from repository list in OpenSuse 42.3

Tags: opensuse

I'm using OpenSuse 42.3.
It came with default java version 8. I uninstalled it and ithem installed JDK 9 version.

Whenever I do `sudo zypper update` I get the below response.

```
The following 2 package updates will NOT be installed:
 java-1_8_0-openjdk java-1_8_0-openjdk-headless
```

Is there anyway I can remove the entities from update repository list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock packages with zypper.

This will then ignore them for any operation.

Example:

```
zypper al package_name
```

The `al` stands for add lock.

You can use `ll` to list locked packages, also use `rl` to remove locks.